# Windows Service Start Arguments

Tags: windows, service

I add the following to the start parameters box on the windows service "-foo", I then start the service without closing the dialog.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //...
}
```

But in the Main of my service, args is empty. Why might this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because these arguments are not passed to `Main`, but the service's [`OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) method. Arguments passed from the command line, however, (for example by executing the service exe from a console) will end up in `args` for the `Main` method.

Answer (score 1):

That would be because services use a different entry point. See [Service Entry Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Service ServiceMain Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In managed parlance the arguments get passed to [`ServiceBase.OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx).